# In ein oder einer bis zwei Stunden?

Tags: usage, article

Ich stehe gerade vor der Überlegung, welche der folgenden Alternativen korrekt sind:

> In ein bis zwei Stunden / In einer bis zwei Stunden

und

> Ein oder zwei Stunden lang / Eine oder zwei Stunden lang

und

> Seit ein oder zwei Stunden / Seit einer oder zwei Stunden

oder

> Nimm Dir ein oder zwei Äpfel / Nimm Dir einen oder zwei Äpfel

Wenn ich das bei Suchmaschinen eingebe, wird mir nur ein Mietwagen angeboten, der Duden spart diese Formulierung aus, wenn man "Stunde" sucht und hier habe ich auch keine Übereinstimmung gefunden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In ein bis zwei Stunden / **In einer bis zwei Stunden**

- Dativ, da hier die Präposition "in" verwendet wird.

und

> Ein oder zwei Stunden lang / **Eine oder zwei Stunden lang**

- feminin, deshalb eine Stunde/ die Stunde und

> Seit ein oder zwei Stunden / **Seit einer oder zwei Stunden**

- Dativ, da hier die Präposition "seit" verwendet wird.

oder

> Nimm Dir ein oder zwei Äpfel / **Nimm Dir einen oder zwei Äpfel**

- maskulin, daher einen Apfel, der Apfel

Erklärung:

- https://www.cafe-lingua.de/deutsche-grammatik/die-unbestimmten-artikel.php
- https://deutsch.lingolia.com/de/grammatik/praepositionen/faelle
- https://www.cafe-lingua.de/deutsche-grammatik/deklination-beugung.php

"ein" ist hier der unbestimmte Artikel zu dem femininen Wort Stunde. Wenn man das feminine Wort Stunde (mit unbestimmtem Artikel nur in Singular) dekliniert, kommt man auf die fett markierten Sätze.

Comment: hab ich angefügt

Comment: Die Quellen sind gut. Man findet Sie aber natürlich nicht, wenn man Beispiele sucht, sondern man muss sein Problem schon beim Namen nennen können.

Comment: Ja das stimmt.
dafür können hier ja Fragen gestellt werden :)

Answer (score 4):

[Die Zahl *ein(s)* wird vor einem Substantiv genau gleich flektiert wie der unbestimmte Artikel *ein*.](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-A/Texte/Kardinalzahlen.html)

Deswegen muss es

> Nimm dir einen oder zwei Äpfel

heißen.

Die Formulierung

> Nimm dir ein oder zwei Äpfel

ist verständlich, aber umgangssprachlich.